# Wildfly PersistenceUnit missing dependencies

Tags: java, web-service, wildfly

I am trying to make a Web Service using wildfly-10.0.0.Final

I am getting the error shown bellow. I already copied/created postgres and eclipselink jars to the Wildfly module folders.

```
05:13:11,312 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "RESTendJPA-1.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"RESTendJPA-1.war#myPS\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.DefaultProject]"]}
```

I have created a datasource through Wildfly administration UI. At the UI, wildfly connects successfully to the datasource.
The **standalone.xml** datasource configuration is shown bellow.

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DefaultProject" pool-name="DefaultProject" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/defaultproject</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>defaultproject</user-name>
                    <password>defaultproject123</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

**persistance.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultProject</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("restendjpa")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(br.com.willian.restendjpa.entities.NewCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.class);
    resources.add(br.com.willian.restendjpa.rest.ResourceFacadeREST.class);
}
}
```

**ResourceFacadeREST**

```
@Stateless
@Path("/resource")
public class ResourceFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Resource> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPS")
private EntityManager em;

public ResourceFacadeREST() {
    super(Resource.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void create(Resource entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Resource entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Resource find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Resource> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Resource> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from,
  @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oi!
O persistence provider me parece errado.

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Pelo que eu lembro o Wildfly usa o Hibernate então seria o abaixo:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Substitui isso no seu persistence.xml e me fala se funcionou.

- Dica: Se você esta utilizando as dependências do servidor e ta deixando o mesmo se virar com as dependências, você não precisa colocar essa informação, pois servidores como Wildfly ou Glassfish dão um jeito de definir isso levando a implementação que eles tem embarcado, é obrigatório mesmo num tomcat ou jetty que não possuem essa característica.

Fala pra gente se resolveu.